# A Polynomial Problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

**Let $P(x)$ be a Polynomial of degree $n$. Show that —**

$\frac{P(x)}{\left(x-\alpha_{1}\right)\left(x-\alpha_{2}\right) \cdots\left(x-\alpha_{n}\right)}=\frac{A_{1}}{x-\alpha_{1}}+\frac{A_{2}}{x-\alpha_{2}}+\cdots+\frac{A_{n}}{x-\alpha_{n}}$

**where $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots, A_{n}$ are constants.**

I think this problem may be incorrect because the degree of LHS is 0 and the degree of RHS is -1.

*If this problem is correct can anyone provide me a hint on how to go about proving this problem?*

Please try to avoid using Partial Fractions.

**Lagrange's Interpolation Formula** may be used because it is given as theory before this problem.

*Thanks in Advance.*

Comment: let $P$ be of degree at most $n-1$...

Comment: @orangeskid yes, that's what I was thinking. The degree must not be n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply both sides by the denominator of the left hand side.
Then if we allow the $A_i$ to run over all constants, we run over all linear combinations of the $n$ polynomials $(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)\cdots (x-\alpha_n)$, $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_3)\cdots (x-\alpha_n)$, up to $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\cdots (x-\alpha_{n-1})$. So this linear comnbination (that we want to equal $P(x)$) is certainly *som* polynomial of degree $\le n-1$. Hence your observation is right: Apparently the problem poser made an off-by-one error or wnated to write "degree $<n$" instead of "degree $n$".

The obvious question remains: Can we obtain every polynomial of degree $<n$ as such a linear combination? This is equivalent to asking whether the $(x-\alpha_2)(x-\alpha_3)\cdots (x-\alpha_n), (x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_3)\cdots (x-\alpha_n), \ldots(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)\cdots (x-\alpha_{n-1})$ are linearly independent. 
This certainly fails if $\alpha_i=\alpha_j$ for some $i\ne j$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check for special cases:

$$\frac{x^2}{(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x-1}$$

$$x^2=A(x+1)+B(x-1)$$

Hence you are right, it is not correct.

I think they left out a constant on the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

Let  $P(x)=$

$A(x-a_1)(x-a_2)......(x-a_n)$, $A \not =0.$

$A \not = \frac{A_1}{x-a_1}+.....\frac{A_n}{x-a_n}$,

a function of $x$, or zero ($A_i=0$, $i=1,2,..n$).